# Find link and send it with form to email

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, forms

How could I make a simple html form (with only name & email) that when submitted a bit of Jquery finds a specific link on the page and send it along with the info from the form to a web server where a script then send an email to the email adress from the form along with the link
the link would always start with the same thing and would look like:

```
http://www.exemple.com/abcd/1u3odjeo
http://www.exemple.com/abcd/340fkdl4
```

This is what I got for now for the form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){

$.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {   
 $('#success').html(response);
 //$('#success').hide('slow');
});
return false;


});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" id="mycontactform" >
<label for="name">Name:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
<label for="email">Email:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />
<input type="button" value="send" id="submit" /><div id="success" style="color:red;"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm missing the link grabbing and how to add that to my script sending the email.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where will these links be on your page?

Comment: Are these links static?  Seems like it would be easier to just include the URLs of the links in hidden form fields.

Answer (score 0):

Get the link from the page, and insert a hidden input in the form before serializing it and sending. You could also just concentenate the link value on to the the serialized string :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mycontactform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $('a[href*="http://www.exemple.com/abcd/"]').attr('href');

        $('<input />', {type: 'hidden', name : 'link', value: link});

        $.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(), function (response) {
            $('#success').html(response);
        });
    });
});
```